# How to display grid of images (GridLayout) in Harmony OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am trying to use TableLayoutManager, to display images in grid view, in ListContainer. But, it is not displaying in the form of a grid of images, but, is displaying a list of images.
For Eg code used is added below,

```
ListContainer listContainer = (ListContainer) findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_recyclerView);
TableLayoutManager tableLayoutManager = new TableLayoutManager();
tableLayoutManager.setOrientation(Component.VERTICAL);
tableLayoutManager.setColumnCount(3);
listContainer.setLayoutManager(tableLayoutManager);
```

Can you please inform, what is the issue in the above code, and how can we achieve a grid of images/items, in Harmony OS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. As confirmed by the team, currently, `TableLayoutManager` is not supported in `ListContainer`. And `grid of images (GridLayout)` function is aslo not supported by now. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation from the HarmonyOS developer website, I think that you will need to set both the amount of columns and rows that you want. https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ui-java-layout-tablelayout-0000001060379893

```
Component component = findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_text_one);
TableLayout.LayoutConfig tlc = new TableLayout.LayoutConfig(vp2px(72), vp2px(72));
tlc.columnSpec = TableLayout.specification(TableLayout.DEFAULT, 2);
tlc.rowSpec = TableLayout.specification(TableLayout.DEFAULT, 2);
component.setLayoutConfig(tlc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find **GridView** Implementation here, using **RecycleItemProvider**

https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/openharmony_tpc_docs/blob/master/widget/GridView.md

and working sample here,

https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/ohos-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/entry/src/main/java/com/nostra13/sample/widget/EasyGridProvider.java